# Prove that $A$ and $B$ are open in $X,$ and that if $X$ is connected, then it is also path-connected.

Tags: general-topology

I am struggling with the following problem:

> Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset, provided with the subspace topology. For arbitrary $x_0 \in X,$ consider the sets $$A = \big \{x \in X: x \text{ can be connected to } x_0 \text{ by a path in } X \hspace{0.2mm} \big \}, $$ $$B = \big \{x \in X: x \text{ cannot be connected to } x_0 \text{ by a path in } X \hspace{0.2mm} \big \}.$$
>
> Prove that $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$ and that $X$ connected $\Rightarrow X$ path-connected.

I am very stuck and do not know where to begin. If I could get a couple hints that could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you prove that $A$ and $B$ are open?

Comment: You must use the openness of X . If X is not open it may fail.Example. $A=\{(u,\sin 1/u) :x\in (0,2)\},... B= (\{0\}\times [-1,1],... X=A\cup B ,... x_0=(1,\sin 1).$ Then $B$ is not open in $X$. But $X$ is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is open:

Taking $x_1 \in A \subset X$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains in $X$. For all $y \in U$, $x_1$ can be connected to $y$, so $y$ can be connected to $x_0$. It implies that $y \in A$. So, $U \subset A$.

$B$ is open: It is similar. :)

Now, if $X$ is connected, we have

> A connected set is a set that cannot be partitioned into two nonempty 
>   subsets

So, what can we say about $A$ and $B$? Obviously, we have $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Because $X$ is open, we have $A$ is not empty. So, $B = \emptyset$. Then $X = A$. Or $X$ is path connected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Open balls are path-connected and form a basis for the topology on $\Bbb{R}^n$. So if $x$ can be connected to $x_0$ by a path, any point in an open ball around $x$ will be connected to $x_0$ by a path.

For the second part, suppose $X$ is connected. What is $A\cup B$? What is $A\cap B$?